# Name 'function' is not defined

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, function

I have a simple issue with a leetcode problem that I need explained.  Other stackoverflow questions that are similar didn't really cut it for me and I'm wondering if it's a problem with my code or if leetcode functions need to be defined a specific way.  Here is my code:

```
class Solution:
    def countNegatives(self, grid: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        arr = []
        for g in grid:
            check(g)     
        return len(arr)
        
    def check(g):
        if g[-1] < 0:
            arr.append(g[-1])
            g.remove(g[-1])
            check(g)
```

I'm getting the error in Line 5 where it says `check(g)` because it is saying `name 'check' is not defined`

From what I can tell, `check` should be in scope, as it is not defined inside of the `countNegatives` function.  I switched the orders of the two functions and that did not matter.  It would make more sense I think if `g` wasn't defined, but it's saying that my entire function isn't valid.  Whether or not the actual code in the function is correct does not matter to me at the moment, but I'm just confused as to why it wouldn't be defined.

Comment: check is in scope but the way it is defined python treats it as a method of an instance of `Solution`. you probably want to declare it as `@staticmethod` and call it as `Solution.check(g)`. (then `arr` will be undefined and you will run into an infinite recursion...)

Comment: It's not defined. You defined `check` as a class attribute, not a global (or nonlocal) function. I would say it should be defined outside the class altogether, but this looks like some non-idiomatic framework that requires an unnecessary class, so `check` should probably be defined as a static method instead, then called with `self.check(g)` in both places.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, that makes a lot of sense.  I don't have much experience with Classes in python and am kind of used to just defining functions willy nilly in a global scope.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is indentation, check is part of the solution class, yet it does not have a self. So either put it out of the Solution class by reducing its indentation:

```py
class Solution:
    def countNegatives(self, grid: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        arr = []
        for g in grid:
            check(g)     
        return len(arr)
        
def check(g):
    if g[-1] < 0:
        arr.append(g[-1])
        g.remove(g[-1])
        check(g)
```

Or pass it self:

```py
class Solution:
    def countNegatives(self, grid: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        arr = []
        for g in grid:
            check(g)     
        return len(arr)
        
    def check(self,g):
        if g[-1] < 0:
            arr.append(g[-1])
            g.remove(g[-1])
            check(g)
```